# Error installing software through terminal

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

well i tried earlier to install oracle java as it was taking quite a time to download so i stopped the process in between now whenever i try to install new software it automatically continue that Java download !!
i tried auto clean , remove command well none does work for me 
PLEASE help me out ASAP

```
utkarsh@utkarsh-SVF15218SNW:~$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
utkarsh@utkarsh-SVF15218SNW:~$ sudo apt-get autoclean
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
utkarsh@utkarsh-SVF15218SNW:~$ sudo apt-get clean
utkarsh@utkarsh-SVF15218SNW:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Comment: You ran four commands but not the one that it asks you to.

Comment: Run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as stated in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you installed a Java package called "oracle-java8-installer" (as an example) you should be able to force-remove it with:

```
sudo dpkg --purge oracle-java8-installer
```

And then you should be able to continue updating the rest of your system with apt-get as normal.